# grep only whole words starting with get_

Tags: awk, grep

In my file I want to `grep` whole words which start with `get_`.

Example: o/p should be:

```
set_output_delay -clock clk_i  3  [get_ports xyz]
set_clock_latency 0  [get_clocks clock]
set_disable_timing [get_pins u_phy/enable]
```

Comment: Why does the output contain text *before* the `get_` when you asked for the word *starting from* `get_`?

Comment: What does "o/p" mean? Is that really the output, as (I think) @JeffSchaller assumes? Please edit your question to be clearer, and provide input and expected output. And please format it for code.

Comment: Perhaps the requirement is to output *lines* in which `get_` starts on a word-boundary?

Comment: As you can see, there's a bit of ambiguity in your question. Please [edit] it to show a sample input and the expected output in addition to the rule you wish to apply. Also see the [editing help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help), and especially the first part about code block formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Use this (GNU grep):

```
grep -oP '\[\Kget_\S+' file
```

or with perl :

```
perl -lne 'print $& if /\[\Kget_\S+/' file
```

or with awk :

```
awk -F'[ \\[]' '{print $1}' file
```

### Output

```
get_ports
get_clocks
get_pins
```

Comment: Good answer, although I understood the question differently.

Answer (score 0):

**Question:**

> grep only whole word starting with get_

**Answer:**

```
grep -P -o '\bget_.*?\b'
```

**Test run:**

```
==> input.txt <==
set_output_delay get_post -clock clk_i 3 [get_ports xyz]
set_clock_latency 0 [get_clocks clock] ==>get_lost<==
set_disable_timing [get_pins u_phy/enable]
$ grep -P -o '\bget_.*?\b' input.txt
get_post
get_ports
get_clocks
get_lost
get_pins
```